# Android stream to rstp server and convert to rtmp using nginx

Tags: android, nginx, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

I trying to get my android device to stream its camera live to a webbrowser.
I read a great tutorial at androidhive about using wowza to do so. However, im looking for a free solution.
I decided to setup on my local machine a nginx server with rtmp module with access from outside the LAN.
Im able to stream my screen using OBS without problem.

---

MY SETTINGS:

In nginx, I'm using the following conf :

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        allow play all;
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            allow publish all;
            allow play all;

            exec_pull c:/nginx/ffmpeg -i "rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test" -f flv -r -s -an "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/pc"

            #enable HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path "c:/nginx/www/hls";
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
        }
    }
}
```

Im really uncertain with the line about ffmpeg...

In my android application, its simple, I took the class from androidhive tutorial here : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/
Im using the libstreaming for android : https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

So, I simply create a RTSP client using the following line :

```
    Matcher m = uri.matcher("rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test");
```

It should create a RTSP client to connect to 127.0.0.1:1935 with RTSP protocol and stream the camera to the "live" application in the "test" channel.
So my nginx should receive something on port 1935 and convert the RTSP to RTMP using ffmpeg right ?

What iam missing to make the whole thing work ? Im getting really stuck and out of idea to try

Thank you !

Comment: Does anyone experienced with Red5 can confirm if it is do-able with Red5 ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use 10.0.2.2 - special alias to your host loop back interface (127.0.0.1)

Change

```
Matcher m = uri.matcher("rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test");
```

to

```
Matcher m = uri.matcher("rtsp://10.0.2.2:1935/live/test");
```